# Concurrency concept in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Regarding the concurrency of VHDL statements, I want to know how the following code is explained with concurrency.

```
entity foo is
   port( a: out bit;
         b: buffer bit;
         c, d, e: in bit);
end;
architecture bar of foo is
begin
   a <= b xor c;
   b <= d and e after 5ns;
end;
```

Questions are:

- Does `a` take the old value of `b`?
- Is `a` going to be updated after 5ns due to the change in `b`?
- Aren't these statements sequential?

Comment: Think of it as connecting a to the output of `xor` gate with inputs `b` and `c` , and connecting `b` to the output of `AND` gate with propagation delay of 5ns. Draw it and understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer :
a will be updated in the delta cycle after either b or c changes.
b will be updated 5 ns after either d or e changes.
(Which triggers an update of a)

The longer answer :

These statements are not sequential, because they appear in the concurrent region.

Formally, each is equivalent to a process sensitive to all of its inputs. Therefore whenever an event occurs on any of its inputs, the process wakes up, performs the operation, and suspends.

The operation results in a "postponed assignment" on its output signal : that is, when this process has suspended, and ALL other active processes have suspended, THEN the assignment happens (or is scheduled to happen at some later time, as in 'after 5 ns`.

When the assignment happens (either in the next delta cycle, or 5 ns later) it causes an "event" on that signal, which schedules all processes sensitive to it to wake up...
So, signals are not just like variables, they are the inter-process communication and scheduling mechanism in VHDL.

More detail here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532

Answer (score 1):

Things are concurrent not because any concept, but because this is HARDWARE. All components exist all the time. Within the process, by the way, too.

If you need that "after 5nsec" in a real device, you must use a clock or whatever REAL, PHYSICAL way to measure that 5nsec.

Comment: And what if the code was used for a testbench?

Comment: Then it is a completely different story, but what are the odds he is asking about testbench and not about FPGA?